# Book about a dog who is an alien that is adopted by a little boy

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I don't remember the title of the book, but I think I can describe it pretty well.

So the book follows this young boy who wants to have a dog but can't because his father is allergic to dog hair. Then, one night, this spaceship crash lands in or near the boy's backyard and out comes this creature that looks exactly like a dog, except that this dog can talk. The boy takes the dog into his house, and the next morning, the father is not happy that the boy has adopted a dog, but the boy points out that the father is not allergic to this particular dog, so the father decides that the boy can keep the dog.

The cover shows the dog wearing a spacesuit and stepping out of what is very clearly a UFO/spaceship.

I would've read it about 15 years ago. I was a kid at the time and it was a kids' book (I assume), so I imagine it would've been published sometime in the late '90s or 2000s.

Comment: So, not 'A Boy and his Dog' then.

Comment: My dog's just hypoallergenic, can't talk or anything.  I feel gypped.

Answer (score 2):

***[Mush, A Dog From Space](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/354464)*** (1995) by Daniel Pinkwater.

> LASSIE, GO HOME -- MUSH IS HERE!
> Now that Kelly Mangiaro's family has moved out of their apartment into a house, she figures her parents will finally let her get a dog. Instead, her mother gets a job, and Kelly gets a baby-sitter.
> Then Kelly comes upon Mush, a mushamute -- a breed not recognized by the Westminster Kennel Club, or by anyone else for that matter, possibly because mushamutes come from the planet Growf-Woof-Woof, in the solar system of Arfturus. Mushamutes can talk, tell time, cook up a storm, and even clean up the kitchen afterwards. Who needs a baby-sitter when there's a mushamute around? Now if only Kelly can persuade her parents to let her keep Mush....

Comment: We'd be grateful if you'd edit this answer to explain how it matches the OP's description. It'd help other users determine how likely this is to be the correct answer.